# Installing Python Library with ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, web.py

This is obviously basic, but can't seem to get started. Working on this [learn python the hard way ex50](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex50.html)

Just need to get access via the password. I have ran macpro$ sudo pip install lpthw.web but I don't know what is the exact PASSWORD to insert. Thanks!

```
 $ sudo pip install lpthw.web
 [sudo] password for zedshaw:
 Downloading/unpacking lpthw.web
   Running setup.py egg_info for package lpthw.web

 Installing collected packages: lpthw.web
   Running setup.py install for lpthw.web

 Successfully installed lpthw.web
 Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password which is requested is your ubuntu user password, What is happening is that you should run the command

```
sudo pip install lpthw.web
```

on your terminal,
when it prompts you to enter a password, it will mention the username such as

```
[sudo] password for <Your Username>:
```

you have to be an admin/SU to be able to make sudo changes to the system

Just insert your current password which you use to login when it prompts you to.

Comment: Unbelievable!! I spent a whole day looking on the web for this solution. Many thanks @Newbie. The good thing that has come out of this search, is that I now realise there are so many other Python Web Frameworks.

Comment: @Fitnessguru glad I could help.